# Creating an HOC gives Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm creating a decorator or a higher-order component (HOC) for my project, which takes in a factory function, and returns another function, which wraps over the component, like this:

```
class X extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hi</div>
  }
}
export default Decorator(factory)(X);
```

or

```
@Decorator(factory)
export default class X extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hi</div>
  }
}
```

The code for my decorator is like this:

```
export default function Decorator(factoryFn) {
  return function decorate(Component) {
    return class DecoratedComponent extends Component {
      static contextTypes = {
        allStyles: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      }
      render() {
        const gStyles = factoryFn(this.context.allStyles);
        return (
          <Component {...this.props} gStyles={gStyles} />
        );
      }
    };
  };
}
```

On running this, I'm getting an error from `babel-runtime/inherits.js`, which says: `Super expression must either be null or a function, not object`.

What is the correct way to create a decorator or HOC which works like I've described above?

Comment: What do you get if you actually `console.log(Component)` before declaring your `DecoratedComponent` class? As it says, it's an object instead of the correct function. What object is it?

Comment: Ah, nevermind... I figured out what was wrong. Yes, it was an object - it was a RelayRouter object from what I could understand. I had run some jscodeshift on my code, and had missed one file, and I was testing that same exact file to see if it worked :-O It's working exactly as it should. Shouldn't work so long... Maybe I just need to hit the bed. Thanks for your time @loganfsmyth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I solved the question, it was a case of bad concentration & mistaken understanding.